# How do I get system wide proxy settings and apply the same for my electron app?

Tags: javascript, npm, proxy, electron, atom-editor

I'm designing a page which is similar to the one in the link :

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1017/can-i-connect-to-skype-through-a-proxy-server

How do I programatically set system-wide proxy in my app, how to configure those manually when user want to opt manual. I'm new to JS as well as Electron, so please redirect for proper solution if I'm not asking a right question here.

Comment: what platform are you trying to do this on?

Comment: electron, using JavaScript for coding, url to load my web contents

Comment: Which platform as in Windows/Mac/Linux? Setting a proxy is going to be different for each of these

Comment: I'm developing for all three platforms. It would be great if you can help me with all three.

Answer (score 7):

You can set a proxy config via command line, when starting the Electron App: `ElectronApp.exe --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:1234` ([documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/command-line-switches.md#--proxy-serveraddressport)). This is not programmatically, but maybe this helps circumventing coding your own solution.

Comment: Your link is 404.

Comment: Note that the server is http proxy server, not socks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to do this with Electron and it will vary by OS. You're going to have to write custom code for each OS.

You'll need to lookup how to do this from code or command line for each platform and implement it yourself. For example [here are some suggestions](https://superuser.com/questions/419696/in-windows-7-how-to-change-proxy-settings-from-command-line) of how to do this using the registry on Windows.

Due to the possibility of abuse you'll likely required admin permissions on any system to make this change.

Comment: Anything else you can share regarding the same?! Approach, guidance , tutorials !

Comment: Added some more detail above. You're attempting something that nobody has probably done before so you're on your own I'm afraid!